# Providing an Empty List to an Optional?

Tags: java, oop, if-statement, functional-programming, option-type

Suppose I have this layout:

```
public void caller(@NonNull List<Integer> param){
  // param COULD BE EMPTY, but it CANNOT be NULL, its not nullable
  if(!param.isEmpty()) function(Optional.of(param));
  // If param is empty then just dont call "function"
}


public void function(Optional<List<Integer>> someParam){
  someParam.ifPresent(...);
}
```

Here is the question: Is not creating an `Optional` based on an empty list correct usage? The confusion I am having is whether we should be providing an Optional regardless if `param` in `caller` is empty or not because it is not null, but I am wondering if this is the right usage?

Comment: If `param` cannot be null, I don't see the point of wrapping it inside an Optional.

Comment: `Optional` was mainly designed to give methods a clear way to denote that they may return a null result as part of their signature. Any time you're using it for something other than that purpose, ask yourself whether there is a compelling reason to use it anyway. If you can't think of one, you shouldn't be using it. In this case, I can't see one.

Comment: Most of the time, `Optional` and `Collection` (`List`, `Set`, etc) sub-types should not be used together, since an empty collection almost always has the same semantics as an empty optional.

Comment: Too many null states: someParam could be `null`, `Optionial.empty()` or  `Optional.of(List.of())`.

Answer (score 3):

1. `someParam.ifPresent(...);` the body of `ifPresent` is always invoked, because there always is an element, even if it's an empty list (you're checking for nullity `@NonNull List<Integer> param`).
2. You're using `Optional.of` instead of `Optional.ofNullable`, so there is always going to be a non-null element.
3. Wrapping list in `Optional` does not make much sense, why not passing an empty list and not processing any elements?
4. `if(!param.isEmpty())` is redundant, because you know there are elements in the list, as stated in 3. why not passing the list for processing?

**tl;dr**: You're mixing an empty list with `null`, wrapping any collection in `Optional` does not make much sense.